# impersonate oozie job - permission issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to execute bash script, which contains multiple hive commands using ozzie and i get security exception (Permission denied: user=yarn, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x)

**Extra info:**

1. The Submit command was done using hdfs user.
2. I have tried using impersonates option (-doas hdfs)
3. Disabling the security check solve the problem but causing different problem (FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask), using:

```xml
    <property>
      <name>dfs.permissions</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
```

I prefer to solve it, using impersonate or something which is more secure.

Stack-trace:

```
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException(Permission denied: user=yarn, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6795)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6777)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6729)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:4495)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4465)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4438)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:830)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:614)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
)'
```

Comment: From root user, execute the command sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user

Comment: The permission of which files/directories do you want change? because it doesn't seems like a good idea to give full control to everyone on everything under '/user' directory.

Comment: Please provide more details... your job.properties file, workflow.xml and the hive script...